# What disadvantages do thermostatic mixing valves have?

Tags: plumbing, water-heater, valve

I will soon be buying a new water heater for my home.  I want to set the heater to keep the stored water at least 140 degrees Fahrenheit (60 degrees Celsius), and use a thermostatic mixing valve to deliver at most 120 degrees F water to the rest of my house (49 degrees C).

I'm wondering if there are any disadvantages to a thermostatic mixing valve.  In particular, do they ever emit loud noises such as a "clunk" when water starts flowing?

(It may well be that there are not really any disadvantages.  If so, great!)

If there are disadvantages, advice on how to mitigate them would be welcome.

Note: the water in my home is as soft as it gets.  (I live near Seattle, and our water is pretty much melted snow from the Cascade mountain range.  The water company actually adds minerals to the water during processing, as water this soft can be slightly acidic and nobody wants water to dissolve plumbing over time.)  So, mineral buildup inside the mixing valve should be minimal.

Comment: Over 2 years from the question, how about an update? Have you installed? Any noise out of it? :)

Comment: It appears to me that there are no significant disadvantages as nobody came up with anything.

Answer (score 4):

This is old, but it also came up on a relevant search so I'll add my $0.02 in in case it's helpful to the next poor sap dealing with this stuff =]

There seem to be multiple types of thermostatic mixing valves, so it may help to define what it means. The type that I *think* the OP is referring to is one that you put specifically on the output of the water heater. Basically the cold water goes into one side, the hot water (output of the water heater) goes into the other side, and the output of the mix valve goes out as the hot water line to your house.

The advantage to such a valve is exactly as the OP stated -- you can keep your water heater at a hotter temperature than may otherwise be safe and then just adjust the thermostatic valve so that the water going to the house is at the correct temperature. Having the water heater at a higher temperature (say 140F) and the output of the valve at the "set" temperature (say 120F) means you aren't using as much of the water from the water heater; it might for example use 5% cold water and 95% hot water (totally making up numbers here) which means your water heater is going to last longer before it runs out of hot water.

A handyman friend of mine recently described it as "turn a 40 gallon water heater into a 50 or 60 gallon water heater!". I can't say if it really makes that much difference or not!

*Disadvantages:* This is the part that I don't feel was answered very usefully so far, so I'll take a stab. I own the house next door to mine and rent it out and recently my tenants told me they no longer had hot water -- rather, the hot water was suddenly only lukewarm at best. I at the time had never heard of a valve like this and had not realized that the house had one! It took a bit of troubleshooting to realize that the water heater was fine, but the water to the house was not. So, here are the downsides I've identified:

- First of all, if you install one and the people using the house don't know it's there / what it is / how to use it... they will be *very* confused.
- While it should be easy to get to if it's installed correctly, that doesn't mean that it will be necessarily easy to repair. In my case I figured out what it was (the valve was old and ruined by hard water) and the repair was pretty simple (replace the valve)... except that I couldn't get the replacement valve locally and it took me a week to get a replacement, during which they had no hot water. I could have done it faster but I'd have had to do a major repair instead of a minor one.
- It is possible but unconfirmed (by me at least) that keeping the water heater at a high enough temperature could shorten the life of your water heater, so that may be a consideration
- More than anything else -- it's one more thing that can go wrong, one more thing to understand, and one more thing to pay for =]

All in all they seem to be pretty cool little devices and I'm considering installing one at my own home.

Comment: Overall I think these mixing valves are a boon.  You can set your water heater to a high temperature (140 degrees F/60 degrees C) to make sure to kill germs like Legionnaire's Disease, while sending lower temperature (120 F/ 49 C) water to the house.  I have one now, and it doesn't make any weird noises.  It's also clearly labeled by the manufacturer. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I would say that the advantages are number one,  it’s comfort, you’re not constantly going back and forth trying to adjusts to get the right temperature and in the process you probably use less hot water and that being the case it probably saves you some money on energy.  Also the main disadvantage, if there’s a problem with it, it’s pretty expensive labor wise and material wise to dig them out from the wall and repair them.

Comment: Do you have any experience with these valves, such as having one in your house?

Answer (score 0):

One disadvantage i've heard of is that some models may freeze in winter. I'm also not sure that every model comes with a back-flow valve at each intake, that can be a issue depending on the pressure of your system.